# How to change the order of Send To menu items on windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, context-menu, send-to

Is there any way to change the order in which the items of menu "Send To" in windows 7 appears when you click the right button?

I have tested a lot of "Windows Context Menu" tools, but any one works for this.

Thanks!

Update: The order of items in menu seems to be by Alphabetical order. Then, the only way i have found it's to rename items to '1_Item1','2_Item2', etc.. or put one underscore before the name of the entries i want to have on top: '_Item1','_Item2', etc..

Comment: I have added a little more details. Not know what more add, because the question is too simple, i think.

Thank you for your feedback

Answer (score 1):

As you've found, SendTo sorts entries alphanumerically, consistent with the default behavior of Windows Explorer. I don't presently have a system on which I can experiment. But [a search](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&newwindow=1&q=%22Windows%20Explorer%22%20OR%20%22File%20Explorer%22%20default%20%22sort%20order%22%20%22specific%20folder%22&oq=%22Windows%20Explorer%22%20OR%20%22File%20Explorer%22%20default%20%22sort%20order%22%20%22specific%20folder%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...5650.8523.0.8851.18.14.0.0.0.0.362.1809.0j7j2j1.10.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..8.1.361...33i22i29i30k1.0.TQob8sJWK6c) leads to sources indicating that Windows Explorer can be persuaded to open a folder with a different default sort order. For example, Lorien ([2010](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-desktop/set-folder-to-display-date-modified-to-show-every/faf856cd-e4b7-42dc-8622-5a0449b93bb0)) elaborates on tutorials for changing the default sort order in Vista.

Lorien also cautions, however, that this sort of tinkering does not work in dialogs (e.g., Save As). I suspect SendTo would be of that nature, and thus may not be able to function as you wish. If so, your original solution may point toward the only workable route, within the standard SendTo folder.

In that case, beyond the approach you have taken, you could rename SendTo items (e.g., giving the most commonly used one a name that begins with the letter A), or prefix their filenames with 01, 02, 03 ... or with other characters (e.g., underscore) to alter sort order. Note also that there is a Shift-right-click extended SendTo menu that might accommodate some of your SendTo items.

Beyond that, there are third-party utilities that might help you to configure the SendTo menu or to create a context menu alternative in lieu of SendTo. Evidently you have already explored some of these (e.g., [FileMenu Tools](https://www.lopesoft.com/index.php/en/filemenutools)). If you are satisfied that no third-party utility can do what you want, that may be confirmation that it is not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to natively modify a context menu in Windows. Typically this is done with a 3rd party software.

[FileMenu Tools](http://www.lopesoft.com/en/filemenutools) by LopeSoft appears to be a popular recommendation is some of the Windows 7 forums.

[image]

[(larger image)](http://www.lopesoft.com/images/phocagallery/filemenutools/en/filemenutools.jpg)

***NOTE: Download and use at your own risk. I am not recommending the software, only suggestion you look into it. Not responsible for anything you do to modify your OS with it.***

Comment: Thank you CharlieRB, but this software it's only to hide or show Items on 'Send To' menu, but not to change his order.

Comment: When I answered this question you had not updated your question. Therefore, I had no idea you had tried these tools. This is a good lesson why details in the question are important as not to waste time with useless answers.

Comment: They are a lot of tools and software to tweak windows context menus. I say in my question 'I have tested a lot of "Windows Context Menu" tools, but any one works for this.', believe me, was really a lot of tools and i don't remember all the names.